# How to run Scikit's gp_minimize in parallel?

Tags: python, optimization, scikit-learn, anaconda, scikit-optimize

I am unable to make `skopt.gp_minimize` run at multiple cores. According to the [documentation](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/modules/generated/skopt.gp_minimize.html#skopt.gp_minimize), the parameter `n_jobs` should set the number of cores. However, setting `n_cores>1` seems to have no effect. Here is a minimal example that reproduces the problem:

```
from skopt import gp_minimize
import time
import datetime


def J(paramlist):
    x = paramlist[0]
    time.sleep(5)
    return x**2



print "starting at "+str(datetime.datetime.now())

res = gp_minimize(J,                  # the function to minimize
                  [(-1.0, 1.0)],
                  acq_func="EI",      # the acquisition function
                  n_calls=10,         # the number of evaluations of f
                  n_random_starts=1,  # the number of random initialization points
                  random_state=1234,
                  acq_optimizer="lbfgs",
                  n_jobs=5,
                  )

print "ending at "+str(datetime.datetime.now())
```

I am trying to optimize `J`. In order to verify if calls to `J` happen in parallel, I put a delay in `J`. The optimizer is set up for 10 function calls so I'd expect it to run for ~50 seconds in series and ~10 seconds if executed on 5 cores as specified.

The output is:

```
starting at 2022-11-28 12:32:30.954389
ending at 2022-11-28 12:33:23.403255
```

meaning that the runtime was 53 seconds and it did not run in parallel. I was wondering whether I'm missing something in the optimizer. I use Anaconda with the following `scikit` versions:

```
conda list | grep scikit
scikit-learn              0.19.2          py27_blas_openblasha84fab4_201  [blas_openblas]  conda-forge
scikit-optimize           0.3                      py27_0    conda-forge
```

Comment: How are you running this?  ... commandline? ... jupyter notebook? ...?

Comment: @rickhg12hs, I'm running in command line. I do `conda activate env_name`, then `python the_script_above.py`. I also tried setting the environmental variables from within the script, via `os`, still no success.

Comment: I played with it a little and got similar results.  I watched `htop` while the script was executing and did see more threads launched, but with this script, more threads actually increased the time a little (overhead, I suppose). I can only guess that any multiprocessing going on doesn't involve calls to the function to be minimized.

Comment: @rickhg12hs, thank you. You're one step ahead though, I can't even get it to run on multiple threads...